# Discord Websocket Stops Receiving Messages After Certain Period Of Time

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, discord

So I've been working on this for a while now and while I have the Websocket staying connected, it stops receiving message events after a certain period of time. I have yet to pinpoint how long before I stop receiving messages, but I had it running over night and I was still receiving heartbeats received and sending logs just fine, but when I went to test a message event, nothing came through my logs. I'm debating adding in a close script that closes the connection after an hour or two and then reconnects, but I figured I would post my issue I'm experiencing here first before going down that path.

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const listenerjs = require("./listener.js");

const initialURL = "wss://gateway.discord.gg";
const userToken = "Token";
let url = initialURL,
    sessionID = "";
let ws;
let interval = 0,
    seq = -1;

let payload = {
    op: 2,
    d: {
        token: userToken,
        intents: 33280,
        properties: {
        $os: "windows",
        $browser: "chrome",
        $device: "chrome",
        }
    }
}

const heartbeat = (ms) => {
    return setInterval(() => {
        console.log("Heartbeat Sent!")
        ws.send(JSON.stringify({ op: 1, d: null }));
    }, ms);
};

const initializeWebsocket = () => {
    if (ws && ws.readyState !== 3) ws.close();

    let wasReady =  false;

    ws = new WebSocket(url + "/?v=10&encoding=json"); 

    ws.on("open", function open() {
        if(url !== initialURL){
            console.log("In resume payload");
            const resumePayload = {
                op: 6,
                d: {
                    token: userToken,
                    sessionID,
                    seq
                }
            }
            ws.send(JSON.stringify(resumePayload))
        }
    });

    ws.on("error", function error(e){
        console.log(e)
    });

    ws.on("close", function close(){
        if(wasReady) console.log("Gateway Connection Closed, Trying to Reconnect...")

        setTimeout(() => {
            initializeWebsocket();
        }, 7500)
    });

    ws.on("message", function incoming(data){
        let p = JSON.parse(data);
        const {t, op, d, s} = p;

        switch (op){
            case 0:
                seq = s;
                break;
            case 10:
                const { heartbeat_interval } = d;
                interval = heartbeat(heartbeat_interval);
                wasReady = true;

                if(url === initialURL) ws.send(JSON.stringify(payload))
                break;
            case 11:
                var today = new Date();
                var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();
                var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
                var dateTime = date+' '+time;
                console.log("Heartbeat Recieved! " + dateTime)
                break;
        }

        switch(t){
            case "READY":
                console.log("Gateway Connection Ready!");
                url = d.resume_gateway_url;
                sessionID = d.session_id
                break;
            case "RESUMED":
                console.log("Gateway Connection Resumed");
                break;
            case "MESSAGE_CREATE":
                listenerjs.listener(d);
                break;
        }
    })
}

initializeWebsocket();
```

So when I checked this morning, my Sent and Received loggers were still functioning, but no messages I sent were going through, yet when I got off last night messages were coming through just fine.